# Is there a noun/verb for the process of growing new leaves on a tree?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, terminology

Deciduous trees shed their leaves (or defoliate) in the fall. What happens in the spring?

I'm looking for words like bloom/blossom, but these refer to flowers, right? Are there similar verb/noun referring to leaves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it:

> **[Leaf out](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leaf+out)** -- [for a plant] to open its leaf buds.
>   *Most of the bushes **leaf out** in mid-April. The trees **leafed out** early this year*.
>
> **[Leaf out](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leaf_out)** -- (intransitive, of a plant) To open its buds.

Example of usage:

> If it seems like some of your favorite trees and shrubs have been slow to **leaf-out** or flower this spring, you are right. ([Michigan State Uni](http://msue.anr.msu.edu/news/why_are_trees_and_shrubs_so_slow_to_leaf_out_this_spring))

---

There's the related expression **bud out**, but I'm unsure whether it has the precise meaning of "leaves sprouting out of their buds" or it's meaning is "buds appearing on branches". Maybe there's some wiggle-room in its usage. An example of usage:

> In early April, soon after the leaves **bud out**, clusters of snowy, 1-inch, white or pink flowers cover each slender branch of this densely foliated shrub. ([Google Books](https://books.google.ru/books?id=JMn6AgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA104&dq=leaves%20%22bud%20out%22&hl=ru&pg=PA104#v=onepage&q=leaves%20%22bud%20out%22&f=false))

An oldish ([1817](https://books.google.ru/books?id=3jXuAAAAMAAJ&dq=leaves%20%22bud%20out%22&hl=ru&pg=PA173#v=onepage&q=leaves%20%22bud%20out%22&f=false)) example of **bud out** indicating the appearance of leaves:

> The verdant leaves **bud out** when you appear,
>   And all the trees their brightest liveries wear;

Another example ([1987](https://books.google.ru/books?id=ziSx1F854OUC&lpg=PA267&dq=leaves%20%22bud%20out%22&hl=ru&pg=PA267#v=onepage&q=leaves%20%22bud%20out%22&f=false)):

> The leaves are covered with a matted, wooly pubescence. They begin to **bud out** early in the Great Basin, frequently in February [...]

From a novel titled *Hacienda* ([1997](https://books.google.ru/books?id=fs7jDcTu2QEC&lpg=PA173&dq=leaves%20%22bud%20out%22&hl=ru&pg=PA173#v=onepage&q=leaves%20%22bud%20out%22&f=false)) - here it's clear that it's the leaves that appear from the buds, not the buds on the branches:

> The trees and brush were just beginning to **bud out**, the delicate leaves barely hinting their future color.

Comment: I was thinking on *sprout*. *On spring the leaves sprout.*

Comment: @Subjunctive - thanks! You might post it as an answer. I'm out to lunch in botanic terminology, and haven't yet googled for "leaves + sprout". I don't want to steal your answer. (0:

Comment: *Sprout* tends to be used for seedlings emerging from the ground.  CopperKettle has it right- it's *bud* and *leaf out*

Comment: @CopperKettle, thanks. I thought there should be some botanical term (like "defoliate"), but "leaf out" seems to fit my intention. Strangely, 'leaf out' does not appear in my (quite old) Oxford dictionary - it has 'come into leaf' instead,  but that doesn't sound good to me.

Comment: @Subjunctive, I thought 'sprout' wasn't quite right, but it turns out that this is one of its meanings (see [sprout](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/sprout)) - so it is a correct answer too. I personally prefer 'leaf out' because it isn't so overloaded.

Comment: A dry branch "coming into leaves" sounds more appropriate than being "leafed out".

Comment: @BasudevM - That might sound more appropriate to you, but that expression doesn't seem to be [found in the literature](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=leafed+out%2Ccame+into+leaves%2Cleafing+out%2Ccoming+into+leaves&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).